# Do I need to make one-to-many relationship to simple model?

Tags: python, django

For example in the case, there is simple model like this.

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=255)
    sex = ???
```

`Sex` field should be Female,Male or None, very easy choices.

However even in this case I need to make model class `Sex` and use Many-to-One relationship to People??

```
class Sex(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=255)
```

Is it possible to make select box for `sex` member of `People` class without making `Sex` Class???

Comment: Simply use [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices) in `CharField` or in `IntegerField`

Comment: Using relations causes non-necessary joins in database. Database is good when you changing it a lot or there are many rows to save. It is better to store data in your code like [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices) or [TextChoices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types) class for this kind of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`choices`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices) option as,

```
class People(models.Model):
    class GenderChoices(models.TextChoices):
        MALE = 'Male'
        FEMALE = 'Female'
        NONE = 'None'

    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GenderChoices.choices)
```

#### UPDATE

to get more control over your choices, use this representation

```
class GenderChoices(models.TextChoices):
    MALE = 'M', 'Male'
    FEMALE = 'F', 'Female'
    NONE = 'N', 'None'
```

Reference: [**Enumeration types**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types)

Comment: THank you very much!! but in admin.py there appears MALE not 'Male' in selectbox

Comment: Are you sure? FYR: [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXdB1.png)

Comment: I mean left side of `MALE = 'Male'` appears in select box, I try like this `TEST = 'Male'` then appears `Test` in select box

Comment: In this particular example, you won't get a result **`MALE`** (full CAP case) since it is not used by the Django. RHS is responsible for the display and db value.

Comment: I see, but when I need to use 2byte charactor instead of Test, there is no way??

Comment: It perfectly solves my problem. thank you !! I need to understand TextChoice more.